# I received a PhD stipend that was not under a fellowship. How do I report it if it was meant to be research funding?

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-1099-misc

Normally my research advisor and professor gives me my stipend through the school, which processes it as a W-2 form. However, he moved to another university in 2018. To give me my funding for research, I was given direct deposits through his new school which the invoice said "Independent Contractor Work".

In theory, the deposit is supposed to make up for the stipends I get normally (reported as W-2), but was treated as such due to him being at a different university.

Since it is not part of a fellowship, but is supposed to replace my stipend, how do I report this? On the invoice it states it is for independent contractor work and lists all the research I have done towards my phd thesis.

Comment: The problem is that while you are getting the same money, you aren't, strictly speaking, receiving a stipend. I don't know if how the new university classifies the expense makes a difference, but there's a chance that you may be on the hook for self-employment tax. (1/2)

Comment: I would consult an accountant, and you may need documentation from your advisor and/or his university clarifying the purpose of the funds. (Though speaking from experience, this could be problematic. Your advisor's new university has no relationship with you, and may not be able to--or care to--treat your payment as a stipend.) (2/2)

Answer (score 2):

Graduate student stipends for which the student receives a W-2 Form from the University are usually paid as *salaries* for employment as a *research assistant* or *teaching assistant* or *graduate assistant* with the latter two title categories requiring the assistant to provide specific services to the University such as teaching a class or a laboratory course or grading homework, holding office hours for students in a course (teaching assistants) or doing programming, computer maintenance, etc (graduate assistants). In contrast, research assistants are generally not required to perform specific services for the *University* but to assist the advisor in carrying out the research proposed in the statement of work of the research grant or research contract that is paying the assistant's salary. Such grants and contracts are technically awarded to the University, but it is the professor who as submitted the proposal to the awarding agency through the University and it is the professor who decides whom to hire as a research assistant. Often, assistantships include a *waiver of tuition and fees* whose value is not included in the wages reported on the W-2 Form; it is a nontaxable perk.  So, the OP should find out what his status is with respect to his University's tuition and fees. Are they still being waived i.e. does he still have a tuition and fee waiver (which many departments still continue to provide for some students who are no longer research or teaching or graduate assistants -- it provides *some* financial support for the graduate students in the department who are otherwise unsupported), or is he expected to pay them if not now, then starting next semester?

With regard to how to report the stipend for which the OP has received a 1099-MISC, questions will definitely be asked by the IRS if the OP does not report this income on a Schedule C, if not when the tax return is filed and "accepted", certainly when the IRS gets around to reconciling the information that the IRS has (it gets a copy of the 1099-MISC Form) with the tax return it should have been reported on. Yes, as @chepner points out in his comment on the OP's question, the OP would be liable for paying self-employment tax, both the employer's share and employee's share of Social Security and Medicare tax) on the income from the stipend payment. On the other hand, the OP may be able to deduct the cost of books and office supplies etc needed for his research on the Schedule C.  The alternative of trying to get the advisor's new university to treat the stipend as a wage paid to you seems more difficult to accomplish.

Comment: thanks for your response. I do have a waiver given regardless of whether I get the stipend. that is, my stipend is separate from the waiver. In this case, should I just try to deduct books, supplies, etc? Would food, uber rides to school, also count? thank you!

Comment: Food _very definitely_ won't count as a deductible expense, and deducting the cost of Uber rides to the University is also out. As a general rule, travel to and from the place of  work is a personal expense and cannot be deducted by a W2 employee or a Schedule C non-employee. So, if you ciaim your place of work is home and travel to the University is travel to a different job location, it is going to be difficult to justify. What's your address shown as on the 1099-MISC?

Comment: The address is my home address, which is the same as the W-2. So I am assuming office supplies are my safest bet? Thank you so much!